# Shell script loop over array passed as argument to multi-argument function?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, homebrew, homebrew-cask

I am trying to do something like this:

```
function install {
  cmd=$1
  shift
  for pkg in "$@";
  do
   if $cmd $pkg; then
    echo "Installed $pkg"
   else
    echo "Failed to install $pkg"
   fi
  done
}

brews=(git node scala sbt zsh caskroom/cask/brew-cask)
casks=(dropbox google-chrome spotify)

install 'brew install' $brews
install 'brew cask install' $casks
```

However, this only works for the 1st element of each of the arrays. Why is not picking up rest of the array elements??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Revised Question

Replace:

```
install 'brew install' $brews
install 'brew cask install' $casks
```

With:

```
install 'brew install' "${brews[@]}"
install 'brew cask install' "${casks[@]}"
```

To understand why, observe:

```
$ brews=(git node scala sbt zsh caskroom/cask/brew-cask)
$ echo $brews
git
$ echo "${brews[@]}"
git node scala sbt zsh caskroom/cask/brew-cask
```

As you can see, under `bash`, `$brews` references just the first element of an array.  By contrast, `"${brews[@]}"` will expand to all members of the array with each member a separate word.

### Original Question

Replace:

```
if $cmd $2; then
```

With:

```
if $cmd "$pkg"; then
```

Similarly replace references to `$2` to `$pkg` in the echo statements.

#### Aside

While you are at it, just in case any arguments contain spaces, replace:

```
for pkg in $@;
```

With

```
for pkg in "$@";
```

Comment: Did as you suggested. Its still only picking up first element. I am on bash 3.2 on OSX Mavericks

Comment: @wrick I see that `brews` and `casks` are defined as `bash` arrays. The way arrays behave under `bash` is _not_ intuitive.  Please see revised answer.